# Coinbase denies transaction: Please complete verifications to send money

Tags: coinbase.com, error

I use coinbase to transfer BTC for few monthes.

Everything used to be ok up to today.

I suddenly got message "Please complete verifications to send money".
I did not ever get this message before. Googling gives nothing.
My phone number is verified and nothing in the settings page explains what exactly is the problem.

Please, share your thoughts - what could this be and what should I do?

P.S.

Of course I wrote to support, but no response yet...

Answer (score 2):

I finally got assistance from the support agent `David`. He has explained the situation in details and helped me to solve the problem.

To pass verifications, I needed to confirm email & phone on this page

https://www.coinbase.com/verifications

Then I uploaded my ID photo on this page:

https://www.coinbase.com/verifications/documents/new

After that I have filled the following form with correct address & credentials:

https://www.coinbase.com/settings/personal_details

After that I was finally able to send the BTC.

Thanks for patiance a assistance, David!